# Discord.py doesn't add fields to embeds

Tags: python, discord.py

So basically I'm trying to do a checkwarns command, but all it shows is the title and the color.

No errors returned. May be a stupid distraction mistake. Thanks in advance.

```
       try:
           embed = discord.Embed(title = f"Infractions for {member}", colour = 0x0f9492)
           i = 1
           mod = await client.fetch_user(modid)
           for user in users:
               if user == member.id:
                   i += 1
                   embed.add_field(name= f"Infraction #{i}",  value = f"**{type}** \nCase ID: {caseid}\nModerator: {mod}\nDate:{date}\n", inline = False )
           await ctx.author.send(embed = embed)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the error in your comment indicates that `user` is a string and not an object, what is essentially happening is that `user`, a string value, is being compared to `member.id`, an int value. To fix this, do the following:

```py
if user == str(member.id):
```

Comment: `Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: With the code shown I thought that `user` was an object, not the actual user id itself. Maybe the reason the field is not being added in your embed is that the condition `user == member.id` is never satisfied. You can try printing something inside the if-statement block to confirm this.

Comment: Okay the condition isn't met, thanks

Comment: The condition probably isn’t met because you’re trying to compare a string value (user) to an int value (member.id). I’ve edited my answer to show you how you could fix that.